# how locate storage jwt?

Tags: angular, local-storage

I would like save jwt in localstorage, for exemple:

```js
  getWbsJwt(){//recupération du jwt 
    let observable = this._http.get(this.wbsGetJwt);
    observable.subscribe(data=>{
      console.log("jwt ========>"+data);
      localStorage.setItem('jwt', data);
    });
    return observable
  }
```

this is the console.log jwt:

```html
jwt ========>eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ3YnMiOm51bGwsImxvZ2luIjoiYW5vbnltIiwibWRwIjoiYW5vbnltIiwia2V5IjoiamVzdWlzbGFjbGUiLCJkYXRlX2xpbWl0IjoxNTI0NjYwNTc3fQ==.hKh+PAkrGY9zYXAWmbH85LUVDHheD2hcfrjJDgQsScM=
```

visual studio said "data" is a object, and we must insert in local storage with string ?

How I must correctly insert my data ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert data into json string.

```
localStorage.setItem('jwt', JSON.stringify({jwtToken: data}));
```

Comment: thank's for reply :), i try save in attribut, but the localstorage is null. i edit in top post

Comment: Try `window.localStorage` instead of `localStorage`.